# Inequalities inside a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I just started learning about the switch command in JavaScript, and was wondering if the cases could be constructed so as to include inequalities (`<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`), instead of equality (`==`). Also, can one control whether it is a strict equality (`===`) or not? The following code does not even bring up a prompt, so I'm not sure if I've coded correctly:

```js
var a = prompt("Please input a number.");

switch (a) {
  case { < 1 }:
    alert("less than 1");
    break;
  case { < 2 }:
    alert("less than 2");
    break;
  case { < 3 }:
    alert("less than 3");
    break;
  default:
    alert("greater than or equal to 3");
}
```

Comment: I think you must go for `if..else` instead of `switch...case`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually possible, if you do it like this. The `case` whose expression evaluates to `true` is executed.

```
var a = +prompt("Please input a number.");

switch (true) {
    case (a<1): alert("less than 1"); 
    break;
    case (a<2): alert("less than 2");
    break;
    case (a<3): alert("less than 3");
    break;
    default: alert("greater than or equal to 3");
}
```

**Note:** Personally I feel you should use `if-else` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I tried running the program without the `+` before `prompt` and it still worked. Is there any reason why you put the `+` in?

Comment: @ahorn Bcoz the typeof the value you get from prompt is a `string`. Just to make sure to convert it to number i use the unary operator `+`. It still works bcoz in this case the JS do type conversion when evaluating (a<1), etc. But if you give `a` as 1 and check `a===1` it will give you false since no type conversion take place.